# C# thread and exception "Sequence contains more than one matching element"

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispatcher

This feature updates the list of active users. Remove those who are not in the server list. Added those who are not in the client list. The function is called from different threads, but to avoid confusion I put everything in the processing queue Dispatcher

```
//This function is called from different threads
        public void UpdateUsers(List<ServerUser> serverUsers)
        {
            //imitation one thread mode 
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                //remove old user
                ClientUsers.ToList().ForEach(clientUser =>
                {
                    if (serverUsers.All(serverUser => clientUser.Id != serverUser.Id))
                    {
                        OnUserEvent(clientUser, false);
                        ClientUsers.Remove(clientUser);
                    }
                });

                serverUsers.ForEach(serverUser =>
                {
                    var clientUser = ClientUsers.SingleOrDefault(clientUser => serverUser.Id == clientUser.Id);

                    //Add new user
                    if (clientUser == null)
                    {
                        clientUser = new ClientUser(serverUser);
                        ClientUsers.Add(clientUser);
                    }
                });

            }), DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle).Wait();//Wait completion!!!
        }
```

As a result, I get it
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault [TSource] (IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)

**Where am I wrong?**

Comment: Your `ClientUsers` collection must contain more than one entry whose ID matches the given server user in a particular iteration of `serverUsers.ForEach`.  Should it?  If not, your problem lies elsewhere...

Comment: It's saying that there is more than one matching element with a given Id. Why not using `FirstOrDefault` instead. It'll return only a single object, but it'll tell you if it exists or not.

Comment: @Jdsfighter That's fine if `ClientUsers` is expected to potentially have more than one matching element in it, if not (perhaps indicated by the use of `SingleOrDefault`), then changing to `FirstOrDefault` may just hide an underlying issue that will crop up elsewhere.

Comment: Side note: Except/Distinct would likely express what you trying to do in much more readable way...

Comment: My Client Users collection should not have repeated elements with id! That is why I use the function SingleOrDefault. But I do not understand how there is two elements with the same id, if the addition of elements occurs only in that case if SingleOrDefault() == null!

Comment: Is there anywhere else in your code that possible manipulates `ClientUsers`? Perhaps you could put a conditional breakpoint in and pinpoint how exactly this error is occurring.

Comment: Nowhere in the code is no longer changed collection elements. There are read-only.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in on the add new user code and see what you come up with. The only thing I could possible imagine happening is two threads hitting that section of code at exactly the same time, both of them returning no record, and then both of them proceeding to add the user to the collection.

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to answer the question. Based on your claims so far -- that this is the only code can adds elements to `ClientUsers` -- the only explanation I can come up with is that you've somehow managed to wind up in different dispatcher threads in spite of your best effort to avoid that. Otherwise, your assumption that this is the only code that modifies `ClientUsers` must be wrong. Please improve the question if you still need help.

Comment: Thank you all! I'll look for the cause, it can be really anything else.

Comment: The problem is more that I have such an error does not occur, but other users can be.